# Is $(0,1)\cup(3,4)$ homeomorphic to $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Is $(0,1)\cup(3,4)$ homeomorphic to $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$?**

> Original question: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$
> given by $X_1=(0,1)\cup(3,4)$ and $X_2=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$. Is $X_1 \cong
>  X_2$? Justify your answer.

p.s. Now that I think about it, the phrasing of the question makes the statement seem untrue...

Here are the definitions that I am using:
$(0,1)\cup(3,4)$ and $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology.
$(X,τ)$ and $(Y,τ_1)$ are homeomorphic if there exists a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ which has the following properties:
(i) $f$ is one-to-one
(ii) $f$ is onto
(iii) for each open set $U \in τ_1$, $f^{-1}(U) \in τ$
(iv) for each open set $V \in τ$, $f(V) \in τ_1$.

Here is my attempt:
$(0,1)\cup(3,4)$ seems to be homeomorphic to $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$.
Define a function $f : (0,1) \cup (3,4) \rightarrow (0,1) \cup (1,2)$ given by $f[(0,1) \cup (a,b)] = (0,1) \cup (a-2, b-2)$.

(i) $f$ is one-to-one because
$f[(0,1) \cup (a_1,b_1)] = f[(0,1) \cup (a_2,b_2)]$
$\implies (0,1) \cup (a_1-2, b_1-2) = (0,1) \cup (a_2-2, b_2-2)$
$\implies (a_1-2,b_1-2)=(a_2-2,b_2-2)$
$\implies a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$
$\implies (0,1) \cup (a_1,b_1) = (0,1) \cup (a_2,b_2)$

(ii) $f$ is onto because
For any $y \in (0,1) \cup (a-2, b-2)$, there exists an $x \in (0,1) \cup (a,b)$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Listing the basis $B_1$ with elements $v_i$ of $(0,1)\cup(3,4)$:
$\{(a,b):0\le a<b\le1\}$
$\cup \{(a,b):3\le a<b\le 4\}$
$\cup \{(0,1)\cup(a,b):3\le a<b\le 4\}$
$\cup \{(a,b)\cup(3,4):0\le a<b\le 1\}$
$\cup \{(0,1)\cup(3,4)\}$

Similarly, the basis $B_2$ with elements $u_i$ of $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$:
$\{(a,b):0\le a<b\le1\}$
$\cup \{(a,b):1\le a<b\le 2\}$
$\cup \{(0,1)\cup(a,b):1\le a<b\le 2\}$
$\cup \{(a,b)\cup(1,2):0\le a<b\le 1\}$
$\cup \{(0,1)\cup(1,2)\}$

(iii) for each open set $U \in τ_1$,
$f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1} (\bigcup u_i)=\bigcup f^{-1}(u_i)=\bigcup v_i \in τ_1$

(iv) for each open set $V \in τ$,
$f(V)=f(\bigcup v_i)=\bigcup f(v_i)=\bigcup u_i \in τ$

**Does this proof look valid? Are they even homeomorphic in the first place, or did I write a fake proof for an untrue statement?**

Comment: It's not clear how you've defined $f$. What formula defines $f$? That is, if $x$ is an element of the domain of $f$, then which element of the codomain of $f$ is $f(x)$?

Comment: Define $f=id$ on $(0,1)$ and $f(x)=x-2$ on $(3,4)$

Comment: You didn't defined $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f=id$ on $(0,1)$ and $f(x)=x−2$ on  $(3,4)$. This formula defines $f$.